# Remove empty option in the select using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel, ng-switch

I am new to angular js. In my code user changes the value of radio buttons. And depending on the value of the selected radio button, a piece of code is loaded from the ng-switch
HTML:

```
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-repeat="button in modes">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="data.mode" value="{{button.value}}" ng-click="clearObjectIdModal()" name="e_modes">
        {button.label}}
    </label>
  </div>

  <div ng-switch on="data.mode">

    <div ng-switch-when="client">
      <label for="e_selected_object_item_id">Select Client name: </label>
      <select id="e_selected_object_item_id" name="e_selected_object_item_id" ng-model="currentDataItem.object_id" required>
        <option ng-repeat="item in customersListArr" value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.Name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

   <div ng-switch-when="agent">
     // This part is similar to the previous one
   </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Controller part:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.setFile = function () {
  if ($scope.data.mode == 'client')
    return 'client';
  else if ($scope.data.mode == 'agent')
    return 'agent';

$scope.modes = [{
  value: 'client',
  label: 'Client'
},{
  value: 'agent',
  label: 'Agent'
}];

$scope.currentDataItem = data;  // data is preloaded from inputs in form
```

There is also a ng-click="clearObjectIdModal()" that clears the model when switching radio buttons:

```
$scope.clearObjectIdModal = function() {
  $scope.currentDataItem = "";
}
```

The problem is that every time when the radio button is switched to the select value, which dynamically changes, the value of the first option in it becomes equal to undefined. Because in the array from where these options are built there is no such object_id (This is the id that is not there, so an empty field is drawn).
 That is, there are all works. But the first option in the select(after switching to another radio button) is rendered as an empty string.
 There are thoughts, how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you problem correctly but I would suggest a few improvements.

1. change your `setFile` function to as follows

   $scope.setFile = function (){return $scope.data.mode;}

I also do not see the closing brackets for your function in your code. Besides if your function will only return the `data.mode` then why need the function?

2. I would suggest initialize your `data` object properly like:

   $scope.data = {mode:'client'};
3. Change your `clearObjectIdModal` function as:

   $scope.clearObjectIdModal = function(mode) 
   {
     $scope.currentDataItem = "";
     $scope.data.mode=mode;
   }

and in your HTML use it as `ng-click="clearObjectIdModal(button.mode)"`

Comment: Tsungur, thaks for you answer and for you time. But I resolved this question by myself yesterday!)

Answer (score 0):

So in function clearObjectIdModal() I wrote:

```
$scope.clearObjectIdModal = function() {
  if ($scope.e_data["mode"] == 'client') {
    if ($scope.customersListArr.length > 0) {
      $scope.currentDataItem.object_id = $scope.customersListArr[0]['id'];
    }
  }
  else if ($scope.e_data["mode"] == 'agent') {
    if ($scope.agentsListArr.length > 0) {
      $scope.currentDataItem.object_id = $scope.agentsListArr[0]['id'];
    }
  }

}
```

And after this when I change radio buttons the first option in current select(which every time is changed) will be not empty.

Also the problem with an additional empty option is possible to solve when you add a title as the first item in the list:

```
<option value="" disabled>Select</option>
```